# tsql : update table with case statement - whats wrong with it?

Tags: t-sql

I have the following update statement :

```
UPDATE D     
  SET D.Xtra1 = CASE 
                  when ExtendedProperties.PropertyName="Transmittal Number" then ExtendedProperties.PropertyValue 
                  else NULL 
                END, 
      D.Xtra2 = CASE
                  when (ExtendedProperties.PropertyName="File Identification") then ExtendedProperties.PropertyValue 
                  else NULL 
                END, 
      D.Xtra3 = CASE
                  when (ExtendedProperties.PropertyName="File Owner") then ExtendedProperties.PropertyValue 
                  else NULL 
                END, 
      D.Xtra4 =  case 
                  when (ExtendedProperties.PropertyName="Dept File Cabinet") then     ExtendedProperties.PropertyValue 
                  else NULL 
                END ,
      D.Xtra5 = case 
                 when (ExtendedProperties.PropertyName="Record Storage Box Number") then ExtendedProperties.PropertyValue 
                 else NULL 
                END ,
      D.Xtra6 = case 
                 when (ExtendedProperties.PropertyName="ImportCode") then extendedProperties.PropertyValue 
                 else NULL 
                END , 
      D.Xtra7 = case 
                 when (ExtendedProperties.PropertyName="ImageKey") then extendedProperties.PropertyValue 
                else NULL 
                END , 
      D.Xtra8 =  case 
                 when (ExtendedProperties.PropertyName="Boundary") then ExtendedProperties.PropertyValue 
                 else NULL 
                END ,
      D.Xtra9 = case 
                 when (ExtendedProperties.PropertyName="Offset") then ExtendedProperties.PropertyValue 
                 else NULL 
                END ,
      D.Xtra10 = case 
                 when (ExtendedProperties.PropertyName="UniqueFilename") then ExtendedProperties.PropertyValue 
                 else NULL 
                END
```

from  ExtendedProperties inner join data D 
    on D.ItemID = ExtendedProperties.ItemID

the updating isn't working and i have yet to figure out why.

if i do a single direct update statement, it does allow me to write to the field. 
if i do a select just on one of the case statements, it draw the field correctly.

any ideas?

Comment: i'm experimenting with it on 1 record by setting the itemid to a recordno.  none of them seem to be inserting where it should be.

Comment: it compiles fine.. it just doesn't do the update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are transposing a table here. The source table has *N* rows for an item (ItemId, PropertyName and PropertyValue), but the target table has one row with *N* columns for that (Xtra1 … Xtra10).

Left joins can be used to transpose the source from rows to columns and have all values available at the same time, instead of sequentially.

```
UPDATE
  data 
SET
  data.Xtra1  = ep01.PropertyValue, 
  data.Xtra2  = ep02.PropertyValue, 
  data.Xtra3  = ep03.PropertyValue, 
  data.Xtra4  = ep04.PropertyValue,
  data.Xtra5  = ep05.PropertyValue,
  data.Xtra6  = ep06.PropertyValue,
  data.Xtra7  = ep07.PropertyValue,
  data.Xtra8  = ep09.PropertyValue,
  data.Xtra9  = ep09.PropertyValue,
  data.Xtra10 = ep10.PropertyValue
FROM
  data
  LEFT JOIN ExtendedProperties ep01 ON data.ItemID = ep01.ItemID AND ep01.PropertyName = 'Transmittal Number'
  LEFT JOIN ExtendedProperties ep02 ON data.ItemID = ep02.ItemID AND ep02.PropertyName = 'File Identification'
  LEFT JOIN ExtendedProperties ep03 ON data.ItemID = ep03.ItemID AND ep03.PropertyName = 'File Owner'
  LEFT JOIN ExtendedProperties ep04 ON data.ItemID = ep04.ItemID AND ep04.PropertyName = 'Dept File Cabinet'
  LEFT JOIN ExtendedProperties ep05 ON data.ItemID = ep05.ItemID AND ep05.PropertyName = 'Record Storage Box Number'
  LEFT JOIN ExtendedProperties ep06 ON data.ItemID = ep06.ItemID AND ep06.PropertyName = 'ImportCode'
  LEFT JOIN ExtendedProperties ep07 ON data.ItemID = ep07.ItemID AND ep07.PropertyName = 'ImageKey'
  LEFT JOIN ExtendedProperties ep08 ON data.ItemID = ep08.ItemID AND ep08.PropertyName = 'Boundary'
  LEFT JOIN ExtendedProperties ep09 ON data.ItemID = ep09.ItemID AND ep09.PropertyName = 'Offset'
  LEFT JOIN ExtendedProperties ep10 ON data.ItemID = ep10.ItemID AND ep10.PropertyName = 'UniqueFilename'
```

Have a conglomerate index over `(ItemID, PropertyName)` for this to work smoothly if you have many records.

---

**EDIT:** Alternatively, you can do this:

```
UPDATE
  data 
SET
  data.Xtra1  = (SELECT PropertyValue FROM ExtendedProperties WHERE ItemID = data.ItemID AND PropertyName = 'Transmittal Number'), 
  data.Xtra2  = (SELECT PropertyValue FROM ExtendedProperties WHERE ItemID = data.ItemID AND PropertyName = 'File Identification'), 
  data.Xtra3  = (SELECT PropertyValue FROM ExtendedProperties WHERE ItemID = data.ItemID AND PropertyName = 'File Owner'), 
  data.Xtra4  = (SELECT PropertyValue FROM ExtendedProperties WHERE ItemID = data.ItemID AND PropertyName = 'Dept File Cabinet'),
  data.Xtra5  = (SELECT PropertyValue FROM ExtendedProperties WHERE ItemID = data.ItemID AND PropertyName = 'Record Storage Box Number'),
  data.Xtra6  = (SELECT PropertyValue FROM ExtendedProperties WHERE ItemID = data.ItemID AND PropertyName = 'ImportCode'),
  data.Xtra7  = (SELECT PropertyValue FROM ExtendedProperties WHERE ItemID = data.ItemID AND PropertyName = 'ImageKey'),
  data.Xtra8  = (SELECT PropertyValue FROM ExtendedProperties WHERE ItemID = data.ItemID AND PropertyName = 'Boundary'),
  data.Xtra9  = (SELECT PropertyValue FROM ExtendedProperties WHERE ItemID = data.ItemID AND PropertyName = 'Offset'),
  data.Xtra10 = (SELECT PropertyValue FROM ExtendedProperties WHERE ItemID = data.ItemID AND PropertyName = 'UniqueFilename')
```

Less code, maybe easier to understand, maybe not as fast (that's a guess).

Comment: +1, the problem is probably not the UPDATE syntax, but the OP's UPDATE does not work with their schema.  If the column names are an indication then you need a different UPDATE to make  it work for EAV tables

Comment: @phill: P.S.: On a related note, learn to format your code (not for StackOverflow, but generally). Poorly formatted code is one of the biggest code smells of them all. And it's borderline offensive to ask people for help and not even have the code sample straight, just the same way as applying for a job with orthographic and grammar errors all over the place.

Comment: @KM: Not sure what you mean, exactly?

Comment: @Tomalak, it seemed that all the answers were attempting to correct the OP's UPDATE syntax (uae an alias, change your case, etc). your answer joins the EAV table multiple times to get each "column"

Comment: @KM: Yeah, that's right. The syntax was not the primary issue. :) The alternative would be to issue 10 sub-selects in the UPDATE and not do any joining at all. Would be fewer lines of SQL, even.

Comment: how would you incorporate the unique identifiers itemid on the left join?  is it just a matter of adding an extra inner join on itemid?

Comment: @phill: But the left joins *are* tied to the ItemID already. What do you mean by "incorporate"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the `data` table in your FROM clause

```
from  data
join ExtendedProperties on data.ItemID = ExtendedProperties.ItemID
```